# How can I check this in collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have added this collection:

```
Map<String, String> userDataMap = {
              "userName": usernameEditingController.text,
              "userEmail": emailEditingController.text,
              "account": userType  // there is premium and regular account type
            };

...

Future<void> addUserInfo(userData) async {
    Firestore.instance.collection("users").add(userData).catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
    });
  }
```

And actually I don't know how to get info about account type, I would like to print/get value assigned to "account".

This is what I tried but it did nothing:

```
var ok = await Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where('email', isEqualTo: email)
              .getDocuments();
          print(ok);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the document, you have a field called `userEmail` and not `email` therefore you need to do the following:

```
var userDoc = await Firestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .where('userEmail', isEqualTo: email)
              .getDocuments();
userDoc.documents.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data["account"]);
    });
```